# How to add class or id to shortcode HTML elements?

Tags: shortcode, columns, post-class

I have a row elements and 3 columns inside :

```
[row]
[one_third]1[/one_third]
[one_third]2[/one_third]
[one_third]3[/one_third]
[/row]
```

How can I add a custom class or id to [row] element ? I need to squeeze cols 1 and 3 closer to 2 by modifying their margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abandon the shortcodes and use HTML.

```
<div class="row full-width whatever">
[one_third]1[/one_third]
[one_third]2[/one_third]
[one_third]3[/one_third]
</div>
```

OR

you could easily just wrap all of your code in another div and target the [row] element through CSS:

```
<div class="your_special_wrapper">
[row]
[one_third]1[/one_third]
[one_third]2[/one_third]
[one_third]3[/one_third]
[/row]
</div>
<style>
.your_special_wrapper div{ /*whatever css you need*/ }
</style>
```

Comment: while your answer is pretty better than the following "add a parameter class to the shortcode column" it makes the thread a pure HTML/css question

Comment: That is true, but the question was probably made under the assumption that whatever plugin/theme created the `[row]` shortcode may have a specific Wordpress way of handling classes.